# MenuItemTemplate "My Settings" not working on chrome

Tags: 2013

I am doing maintenance on a SP2013 On Premises site, and I have been asked to review an issue with the "My Settings" link not working on Chrome. On IE11 and Firefox, it is sending the user to their profile page, but on Chrome, nothing happens.

Here´s how the HTML element is rendered:

```
<li type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/menuprofile.gif?rev=23" onmenuclick="javascript:GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fuserdisp.aspx?Force=True');return false;" text="My Settings" description="Update your user information, language and regional settings, and alerts." menugroupid="100" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="javascript:GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fuserdisp.aspx?Force=True');return false;" text_original="My Settings" description_original="Update your user information, language and regional settings, and alerts." valorig="" id="mp1_0_0" class="ms-core-menu-item  ">
    <a class="ms-core-menu-link" id="mp1_0_0_Anchor" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" title="My Settings">
        <div class="ms-hide"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/menuprofile.gif?rev=23" alt="" title="" id="mp1_0_0_ICON"></div>
        <div class="ms-core-menu-label" id="zz2_ID_PersonalInformation">
            <span class="ms-core-menu-title">My Settings</span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <span class="ms-accessible"></span>
        <div></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

No error on browser´s console.
Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: I have the solution, do you still need it?

Comment: I too have the same issue. Did you have any solution please share it.

Comment: @ChrisCannon Yes, please :)

Answer (score 4):

After some investigations I found that the menu item "My Settings" doesn't work on Chrome because the click handler has a "return false;" instruction after the first function call.

The menu is generated dynamically from the ie:menuitem tags.
The tag corresponding to the "My Settings" button is :

```
<ie:menuitem id="zz2_ID_PersonalInformation" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/menuprofile.gif?rev=40" onmenuclick="javascript:GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fuserdisp.aspx?Force=True');return false;" text="My Settings" description="Update your user information, language and regional settings, and alerts." menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem>
```

To fix the problem, i loop through the tags to remove the "return false;" instruction in the onclickmenu attribute. My code using jQuery :

```
$welcomeMenu = $("#suiteBar").find("#welcomeMenuBox");
$menuItems = $welcomeMenu .find("ie\\:menuitem");
$menuItems.each(function(){
    $item = $(this);
    var onmenuclickAttr = $item.attr("onmenuclick").replace("return false;","");
    $item.attr("onmenuclick", onmenuclickAttr);
});
```